# On Edit (Google Script)

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function onEdit(e) 
{
var datum = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd.MM.YYYY");
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var newas = SpreadsheetApp.create("Sperren");
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sperren');
sheet.activate();
var temp = ss.duplicateActiveSheet();

range = temp.getDataRange();
range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});

temp.copyTo(newas);
ss.deleteSheet(temp);

newas.getSheetByName('Sperren');
newas.deleteActiveSheet();

var folderID = "Sperr Material";
var folderID2 = "Prozess";
var datei = newas.getRange("C3").getValues();
// var dateid = newas.getRange("G6").getValues();
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderID);
var theblob = newas.getBlob().setName(datei +" "+ datum);
var newFile = folder.next().createFolder(folderID2 +" "+ datei + " "+ datum).createFile(theblob);
}

/* @Process Form */
function processForm(formObject) 
{
var url = "https://https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v03Se_BaW-SqFJpN8TU9oEhT2eSvMRHvqwnh3s14lPY/edit#gid=645028893";
var as = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var ws = as.getSheetByName("Test");

/*ws.appendRow([formObject.material,
             formObject.stückzahl,
             formObject.label,
             formObject.datum,
             formObject.grund,
             formObject.lgort,
             formObject.name,
             formObject.sgrund]);*/

ws.getRange("A2").setValue(formObject.material);
ws.getRange("B2").setValue(formObject.stückzahl);
ws.getRange("C2").setValue(formObject.label);
ws.getRange("D2").setValue(formObject.datum);
ws.getRange("E2").setValue(formObject.grund);
ws.getRange("F2").setValue(formObject.lgort);
ws.getRange("G2").setValue(formObject.name);
ws.getRange("H2").setValue(formObject.sgrund);
}
```

Can anyone help me here, i have Html Formular which sends the values to Google Sheet and Sheet should save on one column.

After that it should be transfer the value to another sheet, where is a specific Table, after that it should be save this table to Drive App with informations.

The first column will be changed by either request and by new change should Google Sheet save a new Datei.

but my OnEdit code will not work

if there is a new change should Google save it to a Folder in Drive APP.

But this onEdit code will not work :)

Comment: `won't work` does not help us identify the issue. Go to the execution page to see if you get any errors and edit the question to include these errors.

Comment: If your expecting the onEdit() to be triggered by anything other than an actual user edit then you will be waiting a long time.  Try reading the documentation for simple triggers you just search the documentation for simple triggers.

Comment: Why can't you call to the function `onEdit` (change the name) from your initial function `processForm`?. As @Cooper said, read the documentation of [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) and [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) too see if they suit you, but I don't think so.

Comment: Explanation of wont work: I tried that with simple triggers that it executes the On Edit code every time the sheet is changed. This is the Trigger Error: Exception: Sie sind nicht berechtigt, SpreadsheetApp.create anzurufen. Erforderliche Berechtigungen: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
    at onEdit(onEdit:5:30). which I can't explain because all folders and sheets belong to me and I am the administrator

Comment: Please, read the documents that I attach you to understand why it doesn't make sense use triggers in this case.